# Android Gradle: Very small file edits took 3minutes to build

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

What is going on? I performed minor edits and upon running with "INSTANT RUN" feature on, the build still took 3 minutes. I am only editing `if` `else` logic. I already have this built for multiple times and even just editing small xml files causes it to build for 3-5 minutes. This IDE is so unusable.

Why is Gradle so slow on Android Studio?

Comment: It can't take too long to run with small changes if Instant Run is enabled, in my pc takes less than 1 minute with bigger changes. Which pc do you use? Are you using the emulator? Is it compatible with Instant Run? Do you have all up-to-date? Are you building the debug variant? You can see other requirements here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html?hl=en-419#instant-run

Comment: That's one of the reasons why I disabled instant run. Gradle alone isn't slow at all.

Comment: Oh, alright. Maybe because its turned on.

Comment: please show some code, there are several operations which cause a full rebuild of your app